# MCG002 Unresolvable type reference 'System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost'

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store

I try solved problem with reference. If I deploy project in debug mode, then is everithing fine but when I switch to releas with .NET native tool chain and deploy it or I create app package then throw this error

[image]

I found some information on internet like http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/0b64e418-0517-4e17-b7d3-a5bde04bd1d2?category=wpdevelop

but it is not very helpful.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share a simple reproduced project in here? In this way we can check this issue more clearly. Besides, please check this article about how to debug .net native issue in UWP:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/29/debugging-net-native-windows-universal-apps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Visual Studio generated automatically this code in my project.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>...\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Drawing.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I just delete it. UWP couldn't include System.Drawing